# Dropdown button react pass json ID into HREF

Tags: reactjs

How can i pass the cls.id into href for button dropdown on react? As you can see in the href part `href="/teams/{cls.id}` doesnt seem to work.

```
return (
          <DropdownButton id="dropdown-team-button" title={this.props.team_name}>
              {this.state.data.map(cls => (
                  <div key={cls}>
                      <Dropdown.Item onClick={this.handleTeamSelection} href="/teams/{cls.id} "title={cls.name}>{cls.name}</Dropdown.Item>
                  </div>
              ))}
          </DropdownButton>
        )
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two common ways of doing it:

**Classic Javascript syntax:**

```js
href={'/teams/' + cls.id}
```

**Template literals on ES6 Javascript version:**

```js
href=`/teams/${cls.id}`
```

Both do the same and work exactly equal.

---

For more information on template strings/literals on ES5 and ES6:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<DropdownButton id="dropdown-team-button" title={this.props.team_name}>
              {this.state.data.map(cls => (
                  <div key={cls}>
                      <Dropdown.Item onClick={this.handleTeamSelection} href=`/teams/${cls.id}` title={cls.name}>{cls.name}</Dropdown.Item>
                  </div>
              ))}
          </DropdownButton>
```